# How to set the integer constraints when use the Genetic Algorithm in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

It would be much appreciated if anybody can tell me how to set the integer constrain for the variables(i.e., they variables can only be either 0 or 1).

```
x = ga(fitnessfcn,nvars);
```

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what you're trying to achieve? By default `ga` will begin with all variables in the range 0..1, and allow them to vary continuously; do you mean that you want to restrict all the variables to be either exactly 0 or exactly 1?

Comment: If so, this may tell you what you need: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/gads/mixed-integer-optimization.html#bs1cihn

Comment: your question barely makes any sense - if you want your output x to be 1 or 0, then set a threshold - if below a certain value then 1 otherwise 0.

Comment: @GameOfThrows, that's not necessarily a good idea: using an optimizer intended for continuous optimization on a forcibly-discretized objective function is liable to work badly. Fortunately, `ga` has a mode of operation where the parameters are constrained to be integers, which I think is pretty much exactly what zdeng is looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the optional `ga` function parameters `LB` (lower bound), `UB` (upper bound) and `IntCon` (integer constraints).  The signature for the MATLAB genetic algorithm function that you want to use is:

```
x = ga(fitnessfcn,nvars,A,b,[],[],LB,UB,nonlcon,IntCon)
```

For example, you could use the MATLAB GA to solve a 10 binary variable problem as follows:

```
% Number of variables
nVars = 10

% Lower and upper bounds
LB = zeros(1, nVars);
UB = ones(1, nVars);

% Variables with integer constraints (all in this case)
IntCon = 1:nVars;

% Run the GA solver
x = ga(fitnessfcn, nVars, [], [], [], [], LB, UB, [], IntCon);
```

Notice that the linear inequality constraints `A` and `b`, and non-linear constraints `nonlcon` are optional and can be replaced with `[]` if they don't exist.

Comment: I am dealing with a similar problem and have an inequality constraint Ax<=b which ga is violating. Could it be because of the large number of variables that I have (10209)? Thanks